# Thunderbird not saving passwords on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, thunderbird

I have 4 computers with Ubuntu 18.04 and in all 4, Thunderbird stopped saving credentials. Every time I open Thunderbird I have to enter passwords and/or OAuth2 authentication information and even when I do that, the Google account does not work. What can it be? Why is Thunderbird not saving this information in all 4 computers at the same time? I checked folder permissions but everything seems to be OK. The problems started yesterday and I haven't installed any Thunderbird updates.

[image: Message after entering credentials for Google account]

For other accounts, it just asks for the password every time and apparently works fine until I close and open Thunderbird again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What worked for was: delete pkcs11.txt in profile

Taken from this: https://support.mozilla.org/nl/questions/1239779

Good luck!

Comment: This fixed a similar problem for me after migrating my profile from Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your answers and the link above - worked for me!

The file 'pkcs11.txt' contains readable ASCII text and has an absolute path to the profile folder, which does not fit after moving the folder.

This was the case when I moved Thunderbird from Win7 to Linux! I renamed the original file, started Thunderbird again and compared the generated file with the renamed one. The diff tool showed only differences in that absolute path.

Comment: Fixed it for me as well.  I did need to *delete/rename* the old file and let it re-create. I think (guess) that will be a CRLF/LF line ending issue, but haven't checked.

Comment: welcome to ask ubuntu! I would suggest this be added as a comment to the answer you mention, since it is important information regarding that answer people may need, and not meant to stand alone as a separate answer :D

Comment: "This was the case when I moved Thunderbird from Win7 to Linux!" same here

Answer (score 2):

Find your profile directory. In default case it name looks like **something.default** and stored in `~/.thunderbird/`. Ok, run `ls -lah ~/.thunderbird/` to view directories in `~/.thunderbird/`. Then when you found your profile name use:

```
cd ~/.thunderbird/<replace to your data>.default
```

and run

```
sudo rm pkcs11.txt
```

Restart thunderbird.